# How to extract text from an iframe in Playwright Python?

Tags: python, html, dom, playwright, playwright-python

I need to extract the text from the second doctype using playwright (mostly) or another tool. (python only)

Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-lang-tag="" lang="ru">
    <head>
    `v`<body class='webp'
       `v`<div id="app">
          `v`<div id="main-container" class>
             `v`<main class="content-wrapper">
                `v`<main class="main">
                   `v`<div data-v-c735354e class="....">
                      `v`#document
                         <!DOCTYPE html>
                           `v` <html data-lang-tag="" lang="ru">

                               `**HERE is what I need - text**`

                          </iframe>
                        </div>
                      </....>
                    </....>
```

With the help of conventional locators, this cannot be done, perhaps someone faced such a task?
When I search for "frame.content()"
The following doctype doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: That's in an iframe. The doctype isn't important. Can you share the actual HTML or site, and your code so far? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the help friend, I already found the information on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to search through

```
frame_locator.frame_locator(selector)
```

in my example it looks like this:

```
page.frame_locator("iframe").locator(".sc-iAEawV > .sc-gikAfH > .sc-iJnaPW")
```